# Python cannot import name 'NUMPY_MKL'

Tags: python-3.x, librosa

I am trying to run a wavenet implementation (which uses tensorflow + librosa). However, I keep running into the error "cannot import name 'NUMPY_MKL'".

I have already installed tensorflow, numpy+mk1, scipy and librosa. Tensorflow itself is loading fine, but error is triggered when I run the wavenet implementation which uses librosa.

My spec/details:
Python 3.5.2
Numpy+MK1 (numpy-1.13.1+mkl-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl)
Scipy (scipy-0.19.1-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl)
Windows 10 x64
Nvidia CUDA v8.0 (cudnn 5.1)

Hope you can help. Full error log below:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 20, in <module>
    from wavenet import WaveNetModel, AudioReader, optimizer_factory
  File "D:\musicAI\wavenet\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .audio_reader import AudioReader
  File "D:\musicAI\wavenet\audio_reader.py", line 7, in <module>
    import librosa
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\librosa\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from . import core
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\librosa\core\__init__.py", line 108, in <module>
    from .time_frequency import *  # pylint: disable=wildcard-import
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\librosa\core\time_frequency.py", line 10, in <module>
    from ..util.exceptions import ParameterError
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\librosa\util\__init__.py", line 67, in <module>
    from .utils import *  # pylint: disable=wildcard-import
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\librosa\util\utils.py", line 5, in <module>
    import scipy.ndimage
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\scipy\__init__.py", line 61, in <module>
    from numpy._distributor_init import NUMPY_MKL  # requires numpy+mkl
ImportError: cannot import name 'NUMPY_MKL'
```

Answer (score 1):

Managed to fixed this by doing a complete uninstall of numpy+mk1, then installing it again.

I was previously doing:

```
pip install --ignore-install path\numpy.whl
```

Do this instead to get it working:

```
pip uninstall numpy # this removes the existing copy
pip install path\numpy.whl # this install the numpy+mk1 from local .whl file
```